# How to connect locally with the Nest thermostat

Tags: nest-api

I am currently working with the nest thermostat and I would like to get/set data locally because local is faster and more secure. And because you don't have to deal with the Nest server (The Nest server is working fine btw - no complains about that).

But I am not able to connect to it locally so.

If I ping to the nest, I get a normal response. It may be a little slow but it is a response.
But that's it. To get a connection the thermostat refuses everything else.

Does someone know a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this isn't possible and is intended to be impossible for the Nest.

The only thing I could think of is if you set up a local Firebase server and isolated both the Firebase server and the Nest device behind a router and while simulating the proper Nest calls, also simulated the responses. This is just a theoretical answer and I don't think it is possible or it would be very difficult if it were.

Comment: This is correct, there is not a server inside the thermostat or smoke detector, only clients for the cloud service.